# When I launched Eclipse this error occured

Tags: eclipse

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.version=11.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2019-07-13 11:25:33.651
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20110815-1438 [2]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1311)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1131)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-07-13 11:25:33.659
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20110815-1438.jar/ was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-07-13 11:25:33.670
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-07-13 11:25:33.670
!MESSAGE Bundle javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201105210645 [1] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 javax.transaction 2 0 2019-07-13 11:25:33.671
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2019-07-13 11:25:33.671
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20110815-1438 [2] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2019-07-13 11:25:33.671
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-07-13 11:25:33.675
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have Eclipse 3.7, this is extremely old and won't work with Java 11.

Either move to a more modern Eclipse such as the current 2022-06 release or switch to an older Java (Java 8 should be OK).